# does switching between thread many times affect performance?

Tags: multithreading, performance, windows-phone-7, listbox, switch-statement

I read from an article which states that we [should adding items in batch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rohantha/archive/2010/09/12/silverlight-wp7-list-scroll-with-items-as-image-description-from-web-bing-image-search.aspx) to improve Listbox 's responsiveness.

In order to do that, we must **switch to UI thread every certain amount of time** (ex. 20ms). Does that affect performance ?

Comment: Literally, overall, yes, it improves it. 'Switching betwen threads' provides fast and efficient handling of I/O - that's 99% of the point of preemptive multitaskers. Threads waiting on I/O or each other only run when there is something to do.  I don't really understand the body of your question - if you signal a batch of listbox updates to the GUI thread from some other thread, then the GUI thread will process the batch and update the listbox.  The time taken for updating visual objects, (especially complex ones like listboxes), swamps thread context switch times. What's with the 20ms?

Comment: @MartinJames thanks. 20ms is just an example. Is time for switching thread > time for UI to update Listbox ? And about the performance issue when switching between thread many times like this ?

Comment: My experience using listboxes in WP7 tells me that 10ms is a great time to let the UI refresh, and the performance improvement is noticeable. If you're adding items to a list, just call to `Thread.Sleep(10)` every 5-10 items added. I don't know exactly why this happens, I think it has something to do with the LB not managing well large chunks of new items added.